# How to get the select box value from jsp to another servlet?

Tags: jsp, servlets, request, dropdown

Here is my jsp

```
<form action = "first"  > <!-- first servlet -->

    <select name="loginAs">
    <option>Fan</option>
    <option>Club Member</option>
    <option>Admin</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Here is my servlet :

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException, IOException {

    String c = req.getParameter("loginAs");
}
```

but it is still showing as null when I use c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add `value` attributes to your options :

```
<form action="first"  > <!-- first servlet -->
    <select name="loginAs">
        <option value="Fan">Fan</option>
        <option value="ClubMember">Club Member</option>
        <option value="Admin">Admin</option>
    </select>
</form>
```